# Facebook Javascript SDK: Tag another user in my wall post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using the Facebook Javascript SDK to allow users to post content to their wall.  In the message that gets posted, is it possible to tag another user, similar to how you can when typing a post on facebook.com? (using something like @person)

We are using:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 'This post came from a test. @someuser'}, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    });
```

The end result would then be a post that tagged the @someuser user.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook API doesn't currently support tagging of users like this. That functionality is limited to the actual site itself.